# php API to upload and download files to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a website hosted on amazon. I want my clients to give access to upload files that are already in their amazon s3 space to my s3 space. Is there any php API that supports this functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon actually [provides one](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/).  And there are lots of examples on the web of using it.  Google is your friend.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon have a [PHPSDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) , check the sample code

```
// The sample code below demonstrates how Resource APIs work


$aws = new Aws($config);

// Get references to resource objects



$bucket = $aws->s3->bucket('my-bucket');

$object = $bucket->object('image/bird.jpg');

// Access resource attributes


echo $object['LastModified'];

// Call resource methods to take action


$object->delete();

$bucket->delete();
```

Or use old s3.php for uploading files to s3 bucket. its a single php file named s3.php
You just download that and from your code . for more read [this](http://www.walkswithme.net/amazon-s3-file-upload-using-php-api).

```
<?php


if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');
//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'YourAccess S3 Key');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'Yor Secret Key');
//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$s3->putBucket("bucket name", S3::ACL_PRIVATE);

//move the file
if ($s3->putObjectFile("your file name in the server with path", "which bucket ur using (bucket name)", "fine name in s3 server", S3::ACL_PRIVATE)) {

//s3 upload success

}
?>
```

Comment: This class is NOT from Amazon. This is a third-party class.

Comment: I have been looking for the S3.php (yes, the third-party class) mostly because it is smaller and simpler than Amazon's PHP SDK. Finally found it here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/master/S3.php