# How to store image directly to AWS S3 bucket, uploaded using fckeditor?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, fckeditor

Recently I have moved my existing site in Amazon AWS and I am in trouble to store the uploaded image or any other file type directly from Fck-editor to Aws S3 bucket. I have search my problem in Google, but not found any proper solution in this regard.

Does anyone have any advise or possible solutions?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this would require the client (here: the browser) to have your *secret credentials* to access S3 to store anything. Unless the system is only going to be used by you alone, providing your secret credentials to random website visitors sounds like a bad idea. You're better off uploading to your server first, which can then store the file at S3. This also allows you to do some validation on the uploaded data first.

Answer (score 0):

I think  its a unique requirement,

you can just hack the FCk-editor uploading section and implement S3 uploads.

Here this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344504/php-api-to-upload-and-download-files-to-amazon-s3/10345203#10345203) will help you to get basic idea of S3 uploads.

Hope its helps..